# MAC OS BIG SUR homebrew can not install openssl

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, macos-big-sur

my macos is big sur
try to install openssl

`brew install openssl`

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully

You can try again using:

brew postinstall openssl@1.1

```
==> An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::EINTR: Interrupted system call @ apply2files - /private/tmp/20210702-73435-1yeffpb

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:207:in `unlink'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:207:in `unlink'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:162:in `close'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:168:in `close!'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/openssl@1.1.rb:156:in `macos_post_install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/os/mac/on_os.rb:8:in `on_macos'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/openssl@1.1.rb:115:in `post_install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1101:in `block (2 levels) in run_post_install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:924:in `with_logging'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1100:in `block in run_post_install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:550:in `with_env'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1089:in `run_post_install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/postinstall.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Big Sur Users

This is because the MACOS disabled this system call
You can test first type below command in terminal

`csrutil status`

by default it is enabled
you can turn it off follow this vedio

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pekCPQn5fMs

after turned off check again you can see

`System Integrity Protection status: disabled.`

and the problem should be solved